# 'cout' was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I'm trying to read in lines from a file using getline, then display each line. However, there is no output. The input file is lorem ipsum dummy text, with new lines at every sentence. Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string line;
    vector<string> theText;
    int i = 0;
    ifstream inFile("input.txt");

    if(!inFile)
        cout << "Error: invalid/missing input file." << endl;
    else {
        while(getline(inFile, line)) {
            theText[i] = line;
            theText[i+1] = "";
            i += 2;
        }

        //cout << theText[0] << endl;
        for (auto it = theText.begin(); it != theText.end() && !it->empty(); ++it)
            cout << *it << endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Also, what does the title of this post have to do with the problem you're having..?

Comment: That's because I didn't edit it after doing some research and then coming across a different problem. What I wanted to know was why I wasn't getting any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<string> theText;
...
while(getline(inFile, line)) {
    theText[i] = line;
    theText[i+1] = "";
    i += 2;
}
```

The first line declares an empty vector. To add items to it you need to call `push_back()`, not simply assign to its indices. Assigning to indices past the end of a vector is illegal.

```
while(getline(inFile, line)) {
    theText.push_back(line);
    theText.push_back("");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<string> theText;
```

Declares an empty vector.

```
theText[i] = line;
```

Try to access to inexistent elements in the vector.

Like it is said in the [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) documentation :

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. **No bounds checking is performed.**

So even if you access an non-existing element of the vector (index-out-of-bound), you will not have any error (unless maybe a segfault...).

You should use [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to add elements to the vector :

```
while(getline(inFile, line)) {
    theText.push_back(line);
    theText.push_back("");
}
```

---

Aside the question :

You can remove `&& !it->empty()` from the last loop, it's useless. If the vector is empty [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) return [`end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) and the code never enters the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `push_back` for `thetext` vector

You're indexing on empty vector

```
   while(getline(inFile, line)) {

        theText.push_back(line);
        theText.push_back("\n");
    }
```

Also remove `!it->empty()` from for loop

```
    for (auto it = theText.begin(); it != theText.end() ; ++it)
        cout << *it << endl;
```

Compile using `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` option .